# Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $12$ generated by $a$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ generated by $a^4$. Find the distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> ***Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $12$ generated by $a$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ generated by $a^4$. Show that the distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$ are $H, aH, a^2H, a^3H$. Verify that $H\cup a^2H$ is also a subgroup of $G$.***

Given $o(G)=o(<a>)=12$ then $a^{12}=e$, $H=<a^4>=\{e, a^4, a^8\}$ therefore, $o(H)=o(<a^4>)=3$. Therefore, number of distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$ $=[G:H]=\frac{o(G)}{o(H)}=12/3=4$.

Clearly, $G=\{e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, \cdots a^{11}\}$. Then the left cosets are $a^rH$,  $~~0\leq r\leq 11$.

The problem can be solved by exploring all 12 cases of $a^rH$,  $~~0\leq r\leq 11$ and then choosing $4$ distinct left cosets will give the desired result.

I have three questions:

1. Is there are any error in the above answer? If there is any modification needed, however small, please feel free to suggest.
2. Exploring all 12 cases of $a^rH$,  $~~0\leq r\leq 11$ and choosing desired cosets is laborious work. Please help me to get the desired cosets so that one can be convinced with the answer.
3. What will be the solution of the last verification part.

Answer (score 1):

1. The biggest problem as I see it is that you use `<a>` as angle brackets, rather than `\langle a \rangle`: $\langle a \rangle$. No real mathematical problems.
2. Saying something like "We note that $a^nH=a^{n+4}H$, so $H=a^4H=a^8H$, and so on." would give you a lot less checking. You would only have to check that $H, aH, a^2H$ and $a^3H$ are actually distinct.
3. You verify that $$H\cup a^2H=\{e, a^4, a^8, a^2, a^6, a^{10}\}$$ is a subgroup, the same way you would in any other case. That means checking that it is closed under the group operation, that the identity element is there, and that every element in the set has its inverse in there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please explore $a^nH=a^{n+4}H$ and how to check cosets are distinct.